# Set YARN application name for Hadoop Distcp job

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, distcp

*NOTE: I don't want to specify a `YARN`-queue name as in [Hadoop: specify yarn queue for distcp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33540752/3679900)*

---

I frequently use [`hadoop distcp`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-distcp/DistCp.html) for moving data around `HDFS` and would like to have a **descriptive application name** for these jobs.

---

Presently all copying jobs just appear with the name `"distcp"` on `Resource Manager` UI and there's no way to distinguish between different jobs.

[image]

---

Is there a way to improve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like many other *MR tools*, `hadoop distcp` also allows you to pass *`mapred` properties* using

**`-Dmapred.property.name=property-value`**

---

so when I use

```
hadoop distcp \
  -Dmapred.job.name=billing_db.replicate \
  -m 10 \
  /user/hive/warehouse/billing_db.db/ \
  s3a://my-s3-bucket/billing_db.db/
```

it appears nicely on `Resource Manager` UI

[image]

---

References

- [Hadoop: specify yarn queue for distcp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33540752/3679900)
- [`Sqoop` *User Guide*: Using Generic and Specific Arguments](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.7/SqoopUserGuide.html#_using_generic_and_specific_arguments)